# How to center two pieces of text using CSS and Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to programming and I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but I'm still having trouble. I'm trying too center two different pieces of text so that they are equal distances from the left and right side and from the top and bottom of the page.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="entrance">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"> Example1  </a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" > Example2 </a></li>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I just can't seem to figure out what I'm missing and I'm sure it's probably something very simple that I'm just not getting. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You r using li tag without ul tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css text-align to achieve what you want. `text-aligh: right` on the left hand `<div>` and `text-align: left` on the right hand `<div>`.

As @Manish mentioned, I also removed the `<li>` wrapper. I also added `col-xs-6` to the `<div>`'s so it works on smaller views too.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/11cLvc2c/3/

Comment: This works well thank you! But I'm still lost on how to get it aligned in the center vertically, I thought maybe     text-align: center would work but it didnt help

Comment: No, text align only applies to the horizontal alignment of the content.

Comment: I still can't figure out how to center it vertically nothing seems to be working, any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

In case you just want to center the text, try this:

Add "text-center" next to each "col-md-6" classes:

```
<div class="entrance">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"> Example1  </a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                    <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" > Example2 </a></li>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In case you'd like to make full centering, I'd recommend to step a little outside from bootstrap and use flexboxes. Flexboxes are new to CSS3 and solve most of our problems. See here for more info:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Here's your modified code:

```
   <style type="text/css">
.entrance{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 800px; /*Put your desired width*/
    height: 400px; /*Put your desired height */

}

.container div
{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;

}
</style>




<div class="entrance">
    <div class="item-1">
        Item 1
    </div>
    <div class="item-2">
        Item 2
    </div>
```

Comment: Alright I have a couple really dumb questions, first dumb question: How do I get flexbox to work? i downloaded it from flexboxgrid and put      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexbox.min.css" type="text/css" />
in my head tag but justify-content still wont work, any suggetions?

Comment: Excellent. Remember, there are no dumb questions while learning. I believe  it's not working because you haven't set a specific width to the container. In my example I apply a specific width and a height.

Comment: Ahh okay, and I can center it at my resolution but if I set it to 1920x1080px or whatever my resolution is wont it not be centered if someone with a different resolution visits the website?

Comment: Would you kindly update your first post (the question) with what you want to do? That way we can help you better ;)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that new to how this site works as well haha.